# Why TSLint problems are not shown in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, tslint

I'm using IntelliJ Idea (Ultimate) and I'm trying to setup TSLint. What I have done so far:

- created a new project
- installed TS & TSLint `npm i tslint typescript -D`
- enabled TSLint in Languages and Frameworks | TypeScript | TSLint | Enable (like suggested [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-tslint-code-quality-tool.html))
- added additional (rather random) tslint.json (see below)
- applied it via right click | Apply TSLint Code Style Rules
- created some ugly .ts file (see below)

but still none of the problems are highlighted. When I run `tslint ugly.ts` in console it shows many problems. TS problems are highlighted:

[image]

I've also checked highlighting settings:

[image]

And here's how TSLint settings look now (Enable checked, Automatic search is set):

[image]

Any ideas what could be wrong?

ugly.ts:

```
/* tslint:enable */

// npm i tslint typescript -D
function a (): void {
    var b = 1;
     if(b){var c=2; var d=5;}
   var  a  =4
      a+b

    var s1 = 'haha'
        , s2 ="ololo"
        ,s3 = `wow`

                 return ;;
}

function b(){return 9}
```

tslint.json:

```
{
  "extends": ["tslint:recommended"],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ]
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotemark": {
      "single": true,
      "severity": "error"
    }, //"jsx-double"
    "interface-name": false,
    "whitespace": [ true, "check-module" ],
    "max-classes-per-file": [ false ],
    "member-access": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "member-ordering": false,
    "semicolon": [ true, "always", "ignore-bound-class-methods" ],
    "variable-name": [ true, "check-format", "allow-leading-underscore", "allow-pascal-case" ],
    "no-console": false,
    "indent": [ true, "spaces", 2 ],
    "no-empty-interface": false
  }
}
```

Comment: works fine for me using your files and settings. Please create a support ticket, providing a sample project and your idea.log

Comment: @lena do you mean create using [this form](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731) or something else? There's also [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA), but I suppose it should work as read-only for users

Comment: both ways will work. Youtrack is public, and you can create new issues/comment on existing ones